Sheaf with no singular support in $\mathbb{R}$-direction decomposes as an external tensor product
Consider $X$ to be a smooth manifold. Denote by $p_1, p_2$ respectively the projections $X\times Y$ to $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Recall the definition of microsupport/singular support of a sheaf (check definition 5.1.2 in "Sheaves on manifolds", by M. Kashiwara and P. Schapira) : Here $SS(F)$ denotes the singular support and $D^b(X)$ is the bounded derived category of sheaves on $X$.

Let $F\in D^b(X)$, then for a point $p=(x,\xi)\in T^*X$, we say $(x,\xi)\notin SS(F)$ iff there is a nbhd $U$ of $p$ such that for any $y\in X$ and any smooth function $f$ defined on some nbhd of $y$ satisfying $f(y)=0, df(y)\in U$, we have $$(R\Gamma_{f^{-1}[0,\infty)}(F))_y=0$$

Now consider a sheaf $G\in D^b(X\times \mathbb{R})$. Assume we know that $SS(G)\subset T^*X\times 0_\mathbb{R}$ where $0_\mathbb{R}$ denotes the zero section of ${T^*\mathbb{R}}$. Then I want to show that $$G\cong H\boxtimes {k}_\mathbb{R}$$ for some $H\in D^b(X)$.
So if $G\cong H\boxtimes k_\mathbb{R}$ then using the microsupport estimates from chapter 5 of Sheaves on Manifolds, I see that $G$ must have microsupport only in $T^*X$ coordinates. If $G$ is given to be such, then I'm not sure what to do. My guess is if such an $H$ exists, it must be given by ${p_1}_*G$. But how do I show $$G\cong p_{1*}G\boxtimes k_\mathbb{R}$$
I found this problem trying to read https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.02598. This comes up in Lemma 5.3 in the paper. They use this as a fact without proof but it's too hard for a beginner like me. Can anyone give some hints?
